# Android: changing text color in ListView based on String value

Tags: android, listview

Perhaps it has been said a lot of times, and I'm sorry, but searching all the web wouldn't help me to find a solution.
I have to make a ListView from an array of String, but I want the color of text changing for each line, for example if the string contains "yellow" word the color of the text would be yellow.
How can I set a thing like this?

Comment: " color of text changing for each line"  Is it possible to have multiple colored text in a ListView?

Answer (score 1):

Create a HashMap with key as color word and value as integer.

Sample code:

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> colorCode = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    colorCode.put("Red", Color.parseColor("Red"));
    // put all pre-defined color in map

    tv.setTextColor(colorCode.get("your color word"));
```

Comment: May not be best solution but might be one solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a simple adapter like this and use it to fill the ListView

```
    public class MySimpleStringAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


        public MySimpleStringAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         String myString = getItem(position);
            //check your string
            //Change the color as you want
            //((TextView)convertView).setTextColor();
        }
    }
```

On the main class

```
MySimpleStringAdapter  mySimpleNewAdapter = new MySimpleStringAdapter (context,textViewResourceId,stringList);
listView.setAdapter(mySimpleNewAdapter );
```

Comment: Thanks guys...Let's try and see if I can get some result ;)

Answer (score 0):

With the last version of Java, you can do switch statment on a String value , so switch on the  string and setBackgroundColor in each case